# git log to graphically show all commits on 2 branches, but only show most recent shared commit

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in git which have diverged a little. I want to display the commits on both. with `git log --oneline --graph --decorate branch1 branch2` I can see the 2 branches, their history (graphically), and where they diverge. But this display shows *all* commits.

How can I do the above command, but stop at the first commit these 2 branches have in common? i.e. I want the last line of the output to be the commit which they have in common, and then see (in the graphical ASCII art way that `git log --graph` shows) the branches diverging.

git version 2.17.1 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate branch1...branch2 --boundary
```

`branch1...branch2` refer to the commits that come after the nearest common commit (excluding the common commit).
`--boundary` prints the nearest common commit (the boundary commit) with `o` instead of `*`.

Or

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate branch1 branch2 ^$(git merge-base branch1 branch2)^
```

`$(git merge-base branch1 branch2)` refers to the nearest common commit.
`C^` refers to the first parent of `C`.
`^C` means to exclude all the commits that come before `C` including `C` itself.
`^C^` means to exclude all the commits that come before `C^` including `C^` itself.

The 1st command is suggested. When the common commit is a merge commit, we need to exclude its other parent commit(s), with `^$(git merge-base branch1 branch2)^2`, `^$(git merge-base branch1 branch2)^3`, and so on. Or with a much long command to exclude all the ancestors of the common commit.

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate branch1 branch2 ^$(echo $(git log -1 --pretty=%P $(git merge-base branch1 branch2)) | sed -e 's/ / ^/g')
```

After searching the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations), the above command could be shortened to

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate branch1 branch2 ^$(git merge-base branch1 branch2)^@
```

`C^@` refers to all the parents of C.